# Unable to line break \title with \maketitle - using custom title package

Tags: line-breaking, titles

I want to use a title page package, `ku-forside`, made for my university, which can be found [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~m00cha/).

The site is in danish, so i will translate the instructions (briefly) to english:
Hit "Zip-fil med ku-forside pakken" to download the package as a .zip file, which needs to be extracted to TEXMF\tex\latex (i use MikTeX i.e. MikTeX\tex\latex). Update the FNDB.

Now, my title is too long for one line, which needs to break into multiple lines. The package disrupts the automatic line breaks that `\maketitle` produce beautifully, and it will not allow me to manually break with `\\`. For good measures, the package transforms `\title` to the danish `\titel`, `\author` to the danish `\forfatter` etc..

Maybe you might know what is causing the issue just by looking at the ku-forside.sty (partly shortened to only include the options i use, i.e. "titelside") before reproducing the issue with my MWE (further below):

```
% KU-forside pakke. Forsider til opgaver skrevet på Københavns Universitet
% Skrevet af Christian Aastrup. Designet af forsiderne følger det på http://www.ku.dk/designmanual
%
\ProvidesPackage{ku-forside}[2007/07/07 v1.0 Frontpages with University of Cph. logos]
%
%Definerer Standard SPROG/AFDELING/FARVE
\def\SPROG{da}\def\FARVE{farve}\def\AFDELING{nat}\def\FORSIDE{titelside}
%
% Laver SPROG-mulighederne til 'if's
\newif\if@en \newif\if@da
%
% Laver AFDELINGS-mulighederne til 'if's
\newif\if@ku   \newif\if@farma \newif\if@hum
\newif\if@jur  \newif\if@life  \newif\if@nat
\newif\if@samf \newif\if@sund  \newif\if@teo
%
% Laver FARVE-mulighederne til 'if's
\newif\if@farve \newif\if@sh
%
% Laver FORSIDE-mulighederne til 'if's
\newif\if@titelside \newif\if@stor \newif\if@lille
%
\newif\if@babel \DeclareOption{babel}{\@babeltrue}
%
% Erklærer sprogene som 'options' i pakke-kaldet
\DeclareOption{en}{\@entrue} \DeclareOption{da}{\@datrue}
%
% Erklærer afdelingerne som 'options' i pakke-kaldet
\DeclareOption{ku}{\@kutrue}     \DeclareOption{farma}{\@farmatrue} \DeclareOption{hum}{\@humtrue}
\DeclareOption{jur}{\@jurtrue}   \DeclareOption{life}{\@lifetrue}   \DeclareOption{nat}{\@nattrue}
\DeclareOption{samf}{\@samftrue} \DeclareOption{sund}{\@sundtrue}   \DeclareOption{teo}{\@teotrue}
%
% Erklærer farverne som 'options' i pakke-kaldet
\DeclareOption{farve}{\@farvetrue} \DeclareOption{sh}{\@shtrue}
%
% Erklærer forsidemulighederne som 'options' i pakke-kaldet
\DeclareOption{lille}{\@lilletrue} \DeclareOption{stor}{\@stortrue}
\DeclareOption{titelside}{\@titelsidetrue}
%
\ProcessOptions\relax
%
% Definerer hvad der skal ske når sprogene er TRUE
\if@en \def\SPROG{en} \fi \if@da \def\SPROG{da} \fi
%
% Definerer hvad der skal ske når afdelingerne er TRUE
\if@ku   \def\AFDELING{ku}   \fi \if@farma \def\AFDELING{farma} \fi \if@hum \def\AFDELING{hum} \fi
\if@jur  \def\AFDELING{jur}  \fi \if@life  \def\AFDELING{life}  \fi \if@nat \def\AFDELING{nat} \fi
\if@samf \def\AFDELING{samf} \fi \if@sund  \def\AFDELING{sund}  \fi \if@teo \def\AFDELING{teo} \fi
%
% Definerer hvad der skal ske når farverne er TRUE
\if@sh \def\FARVE{sh} \fi \if@farve \def\FARVE{farve} \fi
%
% Definerer hvad der skal ske når de forskellige forsidemuligheder er TRUE
\if@stor \def\FORSIDE{stor} \fi \if@lille \def\FORSIDE{lille} \fi
\if@titelside \def\FORSIDE{titelside} \fi
%
\def\OPGAVE{$\backslash$opgave$\{\ldots\}$}
\def\FORFATTER{$\backslash$forfatter$\{\ldots\}$ el. $\backslash$author$\{\ldots\}$ }
\def\TITEL{$\backslash$titel$\{\ldots\}$ el. $\backslash$title$\{\ldots\}$}
\def\UNDERTITEL{$\backslash$undertitel$\{\ldots\}$}
\def\VEJLEDER{$\backslash$vejleder$\{\ldots\}$}
\def\AFLEVERINGSDATO{$\backslash$dato$\{\ldots\}$ el. $\backslash$date$\{\ldots\}$}
%
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\def\FORFATTER{#1}}
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\def\TITEL{#1}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\def\AFLEVERINGSDATO{#1}}
%
\newcommand{\opgave}[1]{\def\OPGAVE{#1}}
\newcommand{\forfatter}[1]{\def\FORFATTER{#1}}
\newcommand{\titel}[1]{\def\TITEL{#1}}
\newcommand{\undertitel}[1]{\def\UNDERTITEL{#1}}
\newcommand{\vejleder}[1]{\def\VEJLEDER{#1}}
\newcommand{\dato}[1]{\def\AFLEVERINGSDATO{#1}}
%
% Pakker nødvendige for at sætte forsiden op %
%
%\RequirePackage[OT2,OT4]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{eso-pic,graphicx,fix-cm,ae,aecompl,ifthen}         %
%\RequirePackage[usenames]{color}
\RequirePackage{color} %
%% BABEL-option: Undersøger det erklærede sprog og sætter pakken Babel derefter %%
\if@babel
\ifthenelse{\equal{\SPROG}{en}}{\RequirePackage[danish,english]{babel}}{} % Engelsk ordeling, overskrifts- og kapitel struktur   %
\ifthenelse{\equal{\SPROG}{da}}{\RequirePackage[english,danish]{babel}}{} % Dansk ordeling, overskrifts- og kapitel struktur     %
% Bemærk at begge sprog indlæses. Rækkefølgen er vigtig, idet det er det sidste sprog som dokumnetet generelt sættes i.          %
% Det andet sprogs orddeling mm. kan man få fat i ved at skrive \selectlanguage{sprog} i brødteksten                             %
\fi
%
%% FORSIDEN DEFINERES:  %
%
% Mulighed: titelside
\ifthenelse{\equal{\FORSIDE}{titelside}}{
\def\tyk{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{bx}\selectfont} %Bold extended                                                              %
\def\tynd{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{sb}\selectfont} % Semi-bold                                                                %
\def\maketitle{\thispagestyle{empty}                                                                                             %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 700 600]{\AFDELING-\FARVE}}}%                                     %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,602){\includegraphics*[viewport=0 600 700 1600]{\AFDELING-\FARVE}}}%                                %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics*{\AFDELING-\SPROG}}}%                                                           %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,583.5){\fontsize{20 pt}{22 pt} \tyk \OPGAVE  }} %                                                  %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,555.3){\fontsize{14 pt}{16 pt} \tynd \FORFATTER  }} %                                              %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,499){\fontsize{22 pt}{24 pt} \tynd \TITEL  }} %                                                    %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,480.5){\fontsize{14 pt}{16 pt} \tynd \UNDERTITEL  }} %                                             %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,92){\fontsize{11 pt}{12 pt} \tynd \VEJLEDER  }} %                                                  %
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(50,66.7){\fontsize{11 pt}{12 pt} \tynd \AFLEVERINGSDATO   }} %                                        %
\phantom{Usynlig, men nødvendig}                                                                                                 %
\newpage \noindent}}{}
```

Here is a MWE for my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,usenames]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=212mm,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[babel, titelside, nat,farve, en]{ku-forside}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Titel                    %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titel{A title that is too long for\\ one line: It\newline needs to break, please break} %
\undertitel{} %
\opgave{Bachelor Thesis} % Findes kun under 'titelside'
\forfatter{Mememememememe}%
\dato{\today}%
\vejleder{Supervisor Name} %  Findes kun under 'titelside'

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use a `\Longstack[]{}` of the `stackengine` package to stack things in a title over multiple lines, if I recall properly.

Comment: There are lots (!) of issues, that can be solved with parbox. So keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround consists in putting the title in a `\parbox`. Comment aside, `ae` and `ae-compl` shouldn't be used any more. Also I replaced `\RequirePackage[usenames]{color}` with `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` (usenames is the default in that case). Also, as cfr pointed out, I suppose the letterpaper format should not be used in Denmark.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=212mm,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[babel, titelside, nat, farve, en]{ku-forside}% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Titel %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titel{\parbox{\linewidth}{A title that is too long for\\ one line: It\\ needs to break, please break}} %
\undertitel{} %
\opgave{Bachelor Thesis} % Findes kun under 'titelside'
\forfatter{Mememememememe}%
\dato{\today}%
\vejleder{Supervisor Name} % Findes kun under 'titelside'

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the point of `letterpaper`?

Comment: @cfr: In Denmark, it seems strange. For exoticism, maybe?

Comment: But look at the next line, which is even stranger.

Comment: The reason why i chose letterpaper is because it was the first format stated in the AJCN guidelines, which is where my paper might get submitted to. My thesis will be handed in digitally so it should not be an issue. Either way, i might change it to A4 after reading your comments, letterpaper is better for wide tables though. Thank you for adressing the xcolor fix. I don't know what ae and aecompl is for, are they safe to remove?

Comment: Yes. They're obsolete extensions, made to solve the problem of hyphenation with accented letters. According to the guide `l2tabu`, they should be replaced with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` in your preamble. If you decide to change the .sty file, use `\Require Package`. Also, it's better to add `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, as all modern systems understand unicode (of course set your TeX editor to use `utf8` encoding).

Comment: if i add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to my preample, i get errors.
I removed ae and aecompl from the .sty so i have `\RequirePackage{eso-pic,graphicx,fix-cm,ifthen}` and added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` to my preample right after `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @Bernard: I had to comment `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in order to get the `ku-forside` package to work. Now the encoding of the rest of my text is messed up. Can you explain how i can add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to my preample and getting it to work with `ku-forside`?

Comment: @Nowak:  I suspect this is a problem with your TeX  editor. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry for not giving you this information. I use TeXstudio, and the default encoding is set to UTF-8. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` worked fine before i used the ku-forside package.

Comment: @Nowak: ku-forside doesn't even mention any input encoding (which is normal for a .sty file). The problem is that if your file has several fragments with different encodings, it *is* a mess. What happens generally is the file is supposed to have one encoding, while it is really in another. Normally, TeXstudio displays the real encoding in the status bar at the bottom. Can you read it? Also, do you have a backup of your original file(s)?

Comment: In the bottom rigt corner of TeXstudio, it says UTF-8. By original files, do you mean the .tex file from before i added the ku-forside package? No i don't, but i have commented the lines i needed to remove in order to get it to work, quite simple to revert everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40679/discussion-between-bernard-and-nowak).

Answer (score 4):

This solves it quite simply, but it is perhaps not the best way. A `\parbox` as also suggested by Bernard does the trick.

I do get an  error with this package, even with only the examples included in the package. I think it might be outdated. It does compile anyway, but it could lead to problems. There's an option-clash for the `color`-package, which I believe is now added by some of the other packages. I solved this by commenting the line `\RequirePackage[usenames]{color} %` in `ku-forside.sty`-file, which should be a safe fix.

I would probably tell whoever is responsible for the template to please update it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,usenames]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=212mm,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[babel, titelside, nat,farve, en]{ku-forside}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Titel                    %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titel{\parbox{\textwidth}{A title that is too long for one line: It\\ needs to break, please break}} %
\undertitel{} %
\opgave{Bachelor Thesis} % Findes kun under 'titelside'
\forfatter{Mememememememe}%
\dato{\today}%
\vejleder{Supervisor Name} %  Findes kun under 'titelside'

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway, if it is the `usenames` option  for `xcolor`  which the clash source, it is deprecated.

Comment: @Bernard Is your answer the same? I'm trying to figure out what the differences are between your `\parbox` solution and this one.

Comment: Solutions are the same, bernard and cfr has many other suggestions on the template itself, though.

Comment: @cfr: Almost the same. Actually, I think (maybe I'm wrong) this one was modified after I posted mine. Personally, I added the images when I saw the whole .sty file and the graphics files could be downloaded, and I changed a couple of lines.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, initially I added the code only, which is the same as now. Right after I added text, and added the image only after I saw your image.